# How to print contents in stack to a file

Tags: java

I am stuck at an assignment probem. The problem asks to convert postfix expression from an input file conver to some specified instructions which resembles the infix expression. The results have to be printed in an output file. Below are the input:

```
AB+C-
ABC+-
AB-C+DEF-+$
ABCDE-+$*EF*-
ABC+*CBA-+*
ABC+/CBA*+
AB-*CBA+-*
ABC-/BA-+/
ABC+$CBA-+*
AB0+/CBA+-/
ABC*+DE-/
AB#CD@EF
```

I was able to print the results in the console using System.out.println which I use as a quality check without problem:

[image]

However, once I start introducing the `PrintWriter` and replacing the `System.out` with `pw`, the results printed to an output file turn into something as below:

[image]

I hope the results in the output file looks exactly like the one in console. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code as below:

```java
public class StackException extends Exception {
    public StackException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Stack {
    private final int stackSize = 100;
    private String[] stackArray;
    private int stackTop;

    Stack() {
        stackArray = new String[stackSize];
        stackTop = -1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (stackTop == -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void push(String input) throws StackException {
        if (stackTop == stackSize - 1) {
            throw new StackException("Stack Overflow. Exiting program now...");
        }
        stackArray[++stackTop] = input;
    }

    public int size() {
        return stackTop + 1;
    }

    public String peek() throws StackException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new StackException("Stack Underflow. Exiting program now...");
        }
        return stackArray[stackTop];
    }

    public String pop() throws StackException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new StackException("Stack Underflow. Exiting program now...");
        }
        return stackArray[stackTop--];
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PostFixEval {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws StackException, IOException {
        File fin = new File(args[0]);
        boolean fileExist = fin.exists();

        File fout = new File(args[1]);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fout));

        if(fileExist == true) {
            pw.println("\n" + "\t\t\t\t" + "--- EVALUATION BEGINS ---");
            parseFromFile(args[0], args[1]);
        } 
        else {
            translate(args[0], args[1]);
        }    
        pw.println("\t\t\t\t" + "--- EVALUATION COMLETE ---" + "\n");

        pw.close();
    }

    public static void parseFromFile(String input, String output) throws IOException{
        String line = null;
        int lineCounter = 0;

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(output));

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));

            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    lineCounter++;
                    pw.println("EXAMPLE " + lineCounter + ": ");
                    pw.println("Postfix Expression: " + line);

                    try {
                        translate(line, output);
                    } catch (StackException e){
                        pw.println("ERROR: Invalid expression encountered: exiting");
                        pw.println(e);
                    }

                    pw.println("\n");
                }

                br.close();

            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                pw.println("EOF encountered");
            }

        } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            pw.println("Cannot find file: " + input);
            return;
        }
        pw.close();
    }

    private static boolean isOperator(String operator) {
        switch(operator) {
            case "+":
            case "-":
            case "*":
            case "/":
            case "$":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private static String instruction(String oper) {
        switch(oper) {
            case "+":
                return "AD";
            case "-":
                return "SB";
            case "*":
                return "ML";
            case "/":
                return "DV";
            case "$":
                return "EX";
            default:
                return "N/A";
        }
    }

    public static void translate(String expression, String outputFile)
            throws StackException, IOException {

        Stack variables = new Stack();
        int tempNum = 1;
        String arg1;
        String arg2;
        String op;
        String command;

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

        pw.println("Instructions in the Register:");

        if (expression.trim().length() == 0) {
            throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK");
        }

        for (int i=0; i<expression.length(); i++){
            //if operator, pop arguments and evaluate
            if (isOperator(expression.substring(i, i+1))){
                if (variables.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK");
                }

                command = instruction(expression.substring(i, i+1));

                try {
                    arg1 = variables.pop();
                } catch (StackException e) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK ON ARG1");
                }

                try {
                    arg2 = variables.pop();
                } catch (StackException e) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK ON ARG2");
                }

                variables.push("TEMP" + tempNum);
                pw.println("LD " + arg2);
                pw.println(command + " " + arg1);
                pw.println("ST " + "TEMP" + tempNum);
                tempNum++;


            } else if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i))) {
                //if variab.l+ng(i, i+1));
            } else if (Character.isWhitespace(expression.charAt(i))) {
                //Ignore whitespace
                continue;
            } else {
                throw new StackException("Unrecognized characterr: " +
                        expression.charAt(i) +
                        " at position: " + i);
            }
        }

        if (variables.isEmpty() == false) {
            while (variables.isEmpty() == false) {
                if (variables.pop().startsWith("TEMP") == false){
                    throw new StackException("Leftover variables after evaluation.");
                }
            }
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon me if I am asking a silly question, but have you tried debugging your program?

Comment: You need to pass `pw` to your `translate` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a `PrintWriter` in method `main()` of class `PostFixEval`, so rather than pass the name of the output file to methods `parseFromFile()` and `translate()`, pass the `PrintWriter` and don't create more new `PrintWriter` objects in those methods.

However that is not your problem. From the code you posted, your problem is in method `translate()` with this line of your code

```java
else if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i))) {
```

If the condition is true, you do nothing. You need to push that character onto the stack. I don't see how replacing `System.out` with `PrintWriter` causes the problem, as you claim. Even when using `System.out` your code still contains a bug.

Here is my rewrite of your code with the fixes and modifications described above. Note that I only changed class `PostFixEval` so I am only posting that class.

```java
import java.io.*;

public class PostFixEval {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws StackException, IOException {
        File fin = new File(args[0]);
        boolean fileExist = fin.exists();

        File fout = new File(args[1]);
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fout))) {
            if (fileExist == true) {
                pw.println("\n" + "\t\t\t\t" + "--- EVALUATION BEGINS ---");
                parseFromFile(args[0], pw);
            }
            else {
                translate(args[0], pw);
            }
            pw.println("\t\t\t\t" + "--- EVALUATION COMLETE ---" + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static void parseFromFile(String input, PrintWriter pw) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        int lineCounter = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));

            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    lineCounter++;
                    pw.println("EXAMPLE " + lineCounter + ": ");
                    pw.println("Postfix Expression: " + line);

                    try {
                        translate(line, pw);
                    }
                    catch (StackException e) {
                        pw.println("ERROR: Invalid expression encountered: exiting");
                        pw.println(e);
                    }
                    pw.println("\n");
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                pw.println("EOF encountered");
            }

        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            pw.println("Cannot find file: " + input);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isOperator(String operator) {
        switch (operator) {
            case "+":
            case "-":
            case "*":
            case "/":
            case "$":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private static String instruction(String oper) {
        switch (oper) {
            case "+":
                return "AD";
            case "-":
                return "SB";
            case "*":
                return "ML";
            case "/":
                return "DV";
            case "$":
                return "EX";
            default:
                return "N/A";
        }
    }

    public static void translate(String expression, PrintWriter pw) throws StackException, IOException {
        Stack variables = new Stack();
        int tempNum = 1;
        String arg1;
        String arg2;
        String command;

        pw.println("Instructions in the Register:");
        if (expression == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null expression");
        }
        expression = expression.trim();
        if (expression.length() == 0) {
            throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK");
        }
        int limit = expression.length() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            String argument = expression.substring(i, i + 1);
            // if operator, pop arguments and evaluate
            if (isOperator(argument)) {
                if (variables.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK");
                }
                command = instruction(expression.substring(i, i + 1));
                try {
                    arg1 = variables.pop();
                }
                catch (StackException e) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK ON ARG1");
                }

                try {
                    arg2 = variables.pop();
                }
                catch (StackException e) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK ON ARG2");
                }

                variables.push("TEMP" + tempNum);
                pw.println("LD " + arg2);
                pw.println(command + " " + arg1);
                pw.println("ST " + "TEMP" + tempNum);
                tempNum++;
            }
            else if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i))) {
                variables.push(argument);
                // if variab.l+ng(i, i+1));
            }
            else if (Character.isWhitespace(expression.charAt(i))) {
                // Ignore whitespace
                continue;
            }
            else {
                throw new StackException(
                        "Unrecognized characterr: " + expression.charAt(i) + " at position: " + i);
            }
        }

        if (variables.isEmpty() == false) {
            while (variables.isEmpty() == false) {
                if (variables.pop().startsWith("TEMP") == false) {
                    throw new StackException("Leftover variables after evaluation.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the contents of the output file.

```
                --- EVALUATION BEGINS ---
EXAMPLE 1: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
ERROR: Invalid expression encountered: exiting
gnrltsts.StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 2: 
Postfix Expression: ABC+-
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP1
ERROR: Invalid expression encountered: exiting
gnrltsts.StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 3: 
Postfix Expression: AB-C+DEF-+$
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
AD C
ST TEMP2
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP3
LD D
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4


EXAMPLE 4: 
Postfix Expression: ABCDE-+$*EF*-
Instructions in the Register:
LD D
SB E
ST TEMP1
LD C
AD TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
EX TEMP2
ST TEMP3
LD A
ML TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD E
ML F
ST TEMP5


EXAMPLE 5: 
Postfix Expression: ABC+*CBA-+*
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP1
LD A
ML TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
SB A
ST TEMP3
LD C
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4


EXAMPLE 6: 
Postfix Expression: ABC+/CBA*+
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP1
LD A
DV TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
ML A
ST TEMP3
ERROR: Invalid expression encountered: exiting
gnrltsts.StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 7: 
Postfix Expression: AB-*CBA+-*
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP1
ERROR: Invalid expression encountered: exiting
gnrltsts.StackException: EMPTY STACK ON ARG2


EXAMPLE 8: 
Postfix Expression: ABC-/BA-+/
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
SB C
ST TEMP1
LD A
DV TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
SB A
ST TEMP3
LD TEMP2
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4


EXAMPLE 9: 
Postfix Expression: ABC+$CBA-+*
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP1
LD A
EX TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
SB A
ST TEMP3
LD C
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4


EXAMPLE 10: 
Postfix Expression: AB0+/CBA+-/
Instructions in the Register:
ERROR: Invalid expression encountered: exiting
gnrltsts.StackException: Unrecognized characterr: 0 at position: 2


EXAMPLE 11: 
Postfix Expression: ABC*+DE-/
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
ML C
ST TEMP1
LD A
AD TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD D
SB E
ST TEMP3


EXAMPLE 12: 
Postfix Expression: AB#CD@EF
Instructions in the Register:
ERROR: Invalid expression encountered: exiting
gnrltsts.StackException: Unrecognized characterr: # at position: 2


                --- EVALUATION COMLETE ---
```

Comment: Hi Abra, Thank you very much for your help! I added the pw.close() at the end of the main method. Now the output looks exactly the way I wanted it. Thanks again!!