# How to read line by line using char array (or byte array) in stack problem

Tags: java

This is a follow up question on:
[How to print contents in stack to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445253/how-to-print-contents-in-stack-to-a-file)

I just realized the assignment restricts the use of String functions. I haven't been abel to read line by line using char array. Instead of the result I could get intiatially:

```
            --- EVALUATION BEGINS ---
EXAMPLE 1: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
SB C
ST TEMP2


EXAMPLE 2: 
Postfix Expression: ABC+-
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP1
LD A
SB TEMP1
ST TEMP2


EXAMPLE 3: 
Postfix Expression: AB-C+DEF-+$
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
AD C
ST TEMP2
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP3
LD D
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD TEMP2
EX TEMP4
ST TEMP5


EXAMPLE 4: 
Postfix Expression: ABCDE-+$*EF*-
Instructions in the Register:
LD D
SB E
ST TEMP1
LD C
AD TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
EX TEMP2
ST TEMP3
LD A
ML TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD E
ML F
ST TEMP5
LD TEMP4
SB TEMP5
ST TEMP6


EXAMPLE 5: 
Postfix Expression: ABC+*CBA-+*
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP1
LD A
ML TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
SB A
ST TEMP3
LD C
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD TEMP2
ML TEMP4
ST TEMP5


EXAMPLE 6: 
Postfix Expression: ABC+/CBA*+
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP1
LD A
DV TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
ML A
ST TEMP3
LD C
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4


EXAMPLE 7: 
Postfix Expression: AB-*CBA+-*
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP1
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: EMPTY STACK ON ARG2


EXAMPLE 8: 
Postfix Expression: ABC-/BA-+/
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
SB C
ST TEMP1
LD A
DV TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
SB A
ST TEMP3
LD TEMP2
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: EMPTY STACK ON ARG2


EXAMPLE 9: 
Postfix Expression: ABC+$CBA-+*
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP1
LD A
EX TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD B
SB A
ST TEMP3
LD C
AD TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD TEMP2
ML TEMP4
ST TEMP5


EXAMPLE 10: 
Postfix Expression: AB0+/CBA+-/
Instructions in the Register:
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Unidentified operator or operand encoutered: 0 at position: 2


EXAMPLE 11: 
Postfix Expression: ABC*+DE-/
Instructions in the Register:
LD B
ML C
ST TEMP1
LD A
AD TEMP1
ST TEMP2
LD D
SB E
ST TEMP3
LD TEMP2
DV TEMP3
ST TEMP4


EXAMPLE 12: 
Postfix Expression: AB#CD@EF
Instructions in the Register:
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Unidentified operator or operand encoutered: # at position: 2


EXAMPLE 13: 
Postfix Expression: AB*CD-/E
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
ML B
ST TEMP1
LD C
SB D
ST TEMP2
LD TEMP1
DV TEMP2
ST TEMP3
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 14: 
Postfix Expression: 12*34-+5$
Instructions in the Register:
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Unidentified operator or operand encoutered: 1 at position: 0


EXAMPLE 15: 
Postfix Expression: thisislab1
Instructions in the Register:
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Unidentified operator or operand encoutered: t at position: 0

            --- EVALUATION COMLETE ---
```

Now, after rewriting the code in the PostFixEvalNew class hoping to read the input file line by line using char array, I am getting this instead:

```
            --- EVALUATION BEGINS ---
EXAMPLE 1: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
ABC+-
AB-C+DEF-+$
ABC
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
SB C
ST TEMP2
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP3
LD A
SB TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP5
LD TEMP5
AD C
ST TEMP6
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP7
LD D
AD TEMP7
ST TEMP8
LD TEMP6
EX TEMP8
ST TEMP9
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 2: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
ABC+-
AB-C+DEF-+$
ABC
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
SB C
ST TEMP2
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP3
LD A
SB TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP5
LD TEMP5
AD C
ST TEMP6
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP7
LD D
AD TEMP7
ST TEMP8
LD TEMP6
EX TEMP8
ST TEMP9
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 3: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
ABC+-
AB-C+DEF-+$
ABC
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
SB C
ST TEMP2
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP3
LD A
SB TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP5
LD TEMP5
AD C
ST TEMP6
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP7
LD D
AD TEMP7
ST TEMP8
LD TEMP6
EX TEMP8
ST TEMP9
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 4: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
ABC+-
AB-C+DEF-+$
ABC
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
SB C
ST TEMP2
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP3
LD A
SB TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP5
LD TEMP5
AD C
ST TEMP6
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP7
LD D
AD TEMP7
ST TEMP8
LD TEMP6
EX TEMP8
ST TEMP9
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 5: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
ABC+-
AB-C+DEF-+$
ABC
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
SB C
ST TEMP2
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP3
LD A
SB TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP5
LD TEMP5
AD C
ST TEMP6
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP7
LD D
AD TEMP7
ST TEMP8
LD TEMP6
EX TEMP8
ST TEMP9
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 6: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
ABC+-
AB-C+DEF-+$
ABC
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
SB C
ST TEMP2
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP3
LD A
SB TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP5
LD TEMP5
AD C
ST TEMP6
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP7
LD D
AD TEMP7
ST TEMP8
LD TEMP6
EX TEMP8
ST TEMP9
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.


EXAMPLE 7: 
Postfix Expression: AB+C-
ABC+-
AB-C+DEF-+$
ABC
Instructions in the Register:
LD A
AD B
ST TEMP1
LD TEMP1
SB C
ST TEMP2
LD B
AD C
ST TEMP3
LD A
SB TEMP3
ST TEMP4
LD A
SB B
ST TEMP5
LD TEMP5
AD C
ST TEMP6
LD E
SB F
ST TEMP7
LD D
AD TEMP7
ST TEMP8
LD TEMP6
EX TEMP8
ST TEMP9
The expression is invald. Exiting program now...
StackException: Leftover variables after evaluation.

            --- EVALUATION COMLETE ---
```

Not entirely sure what I did wrong here. Any help is very much appreciated!!

```
public class StackException extends Exception {
    public StackException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class Stack {
    private final int stackSize = 100;
    private String[] stackArray;
    private int stackTop;    //empty stack

    Stack() {
        stackArray = new String[stackSize];
        stackTop = -1;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(stackTop == -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void push(String input) throws StackException {
        if(stackTop == stackSize -1) {
            throw new StackException("Stack Overflow. Exiting program now...");
        }

        stackArray[++stackTop] = input;
    }

    public int size() {

        return stackTop + 1;
    }

    public String peek() throws StackException {

        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new StackException("Stack Underflow. Exiting program now...");
        }

        return stackArray[stackTop];
    }

    public String pop() throws StackException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new StackException("Stack Underflow. Exiting program now...");
        }

        return stackArray[stackTop--];
    }

}
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PostFixEvalNew {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws StackException, IOException {
        File fin = new File(args[0]);
        boolean fileExist = fin.exists();

        File fout = new File(args[1]);

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fout));
        if(fileExist == true) {
            pw.println("\n" + "\t\t\t\t" + "--- EVALUATION BEGINS ---");
            parseFromFile(args[0], pw);
        } 
        else {
            translate(args[0], pw);
        }    
        pw.println("\t\t\t\t" + "--- EVALUATION COMLETE ---" + "\n");
        pw.close();
    }

    public static void parseFromFile(String input, PrintWriter pw) {
        String line;
        int lineCounter = 0;
        char[] content = new char[(int)input.length()];
        int c = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));

            try {
                // while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                while((c = br.read(content)) != -1) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                        // br.read(content);
                        line = new String(content);
                        lineCounter++;
                        pw.println("EXAMPLE " + lineCounter + ": ");
                        pw.println("Postfix Expression: " + line);

                        try {
                            translate(line, pw);
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            pw.println("The expression is invald. Exiting program now...");
                            pw.println(e);
                        }

                        pw.println("\n");
                    }

                    br.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                pw.println("End of File!");
            }

        } 
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            pw.println("File: " + input + " not found!");
            return;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isOperator(String operator) {
        switch(operator) {
            case "+":
            case "-":
            case "*":
            case "/":
            case "$":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private static String instruction(String oper) {
        switch(oper) {
            case "+":
                return "AD";
            case "-":
                return "SB";
            case "*":
                return "ML";
            case "/":
                return "DV";
            case "$":
                return "EX";
            default:
                return "N/A";
        }
    }

    public static void translate(String expression, PrintWriter pw)
            throws StackException {

        Stack variables = new Stack();
        int tempNum = 1;
        String arg1;
        String arg2;
        String command;

        pw.println("Instructions in the Register:");

        if (expression.trim().length() == 0) {
            throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK");
        }


        for (int i=0; i<expression.length(); i++){
            //if operator, pop arguments and evaluate
            if (isOperator(expression.substring(i, i+1))){
                if (variables.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK");
                }

                command = instruction(expression.substring(i, i+1));

                try {
                    arg1 = variables.pop();
                } catch (StackException e) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK ON ARG1");
                }

                try {
                    arg2 = variables.pop();
                } catch (StackException e) {
                    throw new StackException("EMPTY STACK ON ARG2");
                }

                variables.push("TEMP" + tempNum);
                pw.println("LD " + arg2);
                pw.println(command + " " + arg1);
                pw.println("ST " + "TEMP" + tempNum);
                tempNum++;


            } else if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i))) {
                //if variable, push onto stack
                variables.push(expression.substring(i, i+1));
            } else if (Character.isWhitespace(expression.charAt(i))) {
                //Ignore whitespace
                continue;
            } else {
                throw new StackException("Unidentified operator or operand encoutered: " +
                        expression.charAt(i) +
                        " at position: " + i);
            }
        }

        if (variables.isEmpty() == false) {
            while (variables.isEmpty() == false) {
                if (variables.pop().startsWith("TEMP") == false){
                    throw new StackException("Leftover variables after evaluation.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put your inputs and outputs in text form, not as images. It might be easier to see the problem is you put the expected and actual output together.

Comment: If you have to deal in bytes rather than chars, then you might use. FileInputStream rather than a BufferedReader.

Comment: Hi NomadMaker, thank you for your prompt response. I already replaced the desired output and actual output in text. I would hope to stick with char if possible. I just can't read or process the input file as String. So my desired output is reading one line at a time and convert the postfix expression into some machine language. But in reality, it is reading 3 lines in a row as you may see in the actual output. I am not quite sure how to go from there.

Comment: You're getting a newline in the input string. You can use Character.isISOControl(char c) to check and get rid of this. You can also use this to break up your strings into lines.